# Tools for merging java beans

Tags: java, merge, introspection

It's easy to merge two simple, flat java beans using introspection:

```
    BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo( ContactBean.class );
    PropertyDescriptor pDescArr[] = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
    for(PropertyDescriptor pDesc : pDescArr){
        //copy properties and check for conflicts here
    }
```

However, it gets a little more complicated when the properties contain nested beans, or collections. Is there a smart tool somewhere which will handle a deep merge of complex beans?

Some more specifics on just how I'd like the merge to work:

Given a collection of source beans, and an empty target bean, simple properties should be copied over from the source to the target, unless there's a conflict. If there's a conflict, the field should be left empty. If a property is of a collection type, the values of the source beans should be combined, excluding duplicates, and copied to the destination property. These rules should apply recursively to properties which are beans themselves.

Comment: Aside from the fact that there isn't anything in google, the tool would need to be very configurable to decide how to deal with conflicts. What are your rules for the merge?

Comment: @Dave -- added a description of my merge rules to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) or [Smooks](http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Main_Page). Dozer is the winner if you just want bean merge. If you are looking for other usecases like csv to pojo etc then take a look at Smooks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apache common [beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). There is no built in method to do what you are trying to do, but you can use the helper methods in there to achieve the same