# What is the best way to do inline serialization of JSON data using JACKSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've got a bean defined as such :

```java
public static class TestBean {
    private String a;
    private Long b;

    public TestBean(String a, Long b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public Long getB() {
        return b;
    }

}
```

It models some business and I do not get to instantiate it (using JPA). Some of my API let the user retrieve a view of this bean serialize as JSON using Jackson (through JAX-RS) and I would like to add a list of related links to this view.

The normal Jackson JSON serialization would be (for a = "aa" and b = 2L) :

```
{"a":"aa","b":2}
```

And I would like to have the links appear as

```
{"a":"aa","b":2,
 "links":[{"rel":"rel","href":"href://"},{"rel":"rel2","href":"href://2"}]}
```

### Possible work-around

I would rather not add a getLinks() method to my bean, it's specific to this view.

Simply using a composite object would yield a serialization like :

```
{"data":{"a":"aa","b":2},"links":[{"rel":"rel","href":"href://"}]}
```

Which I could live with but is not what I was looking for ultimately.

### Current solution

I would like to avoid manipulating the JSON string or having to reload it into a Map to insert my extra values. For now the solution I've come up with seem awfully convoluted:

Current scary solution :

```java
//a composite view object
public abstract class AddedLinksView<K> {

    private final K resource;

    private final Link[] links;

    public AddedLinksView(K resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
        links = buildLinks(resource);

    }

    public abstract Link[] buildLinks(K resource);

    public K getResource() {
        return resource;
    }

    public Link[] getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

}

//a specific bean serializer
private static class RawBeanSerializer extends BeanSerializer {

    public RawBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerBase ser) {
        super(ser);
    }

    //this is like the standard serialize but without the start and end tags
    public void rawSerialize(Object bean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonGenerationException {
        if (_propertyFilterId != null) {
            serializeFieldsFiltered(bean, jgen, provider);
        } else {
            serializeFields(bean, jgen, provider);
        }
    }

}

@Test
public void usingModule() throws Exception {
    // basic module metadata just includes name and version (both for troubleshooting; but name needs to be unique)
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("EnhancedDatesModule", new Version(0, 1, 0, "alpha"));
    //adding a serializer for the composite view
    module.addSerializer(new JsonSerializer<AddedLinksView>() {

        @Override
        public Class<AddedLinksView> handledType() {
            return AddedLinksView.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(AddedLinksView value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            //looking up the bean serializer that will be used for my resource
            JsonSerializer<Object> ser = provider.findTypedValueSerializer(value.getResource().getClass(), true,
                    null);

            if (ser instanceof BeanSerializerBase) {
                //cloning it in a sub class that makes it possible to 'inline' the serialization
                RawBeanSerializer openSer = new RawBeanSerializer((BeanSerializerBase) ser);
                openSer.rawSerialize(value.getResource(), jgen, provider);
            }
            //adding my links
            jgen.writeArrayFieldStart("links");
            for (Link link : value.getLinks()) {
                jgen.writeObject(link);
            }
            jgen.writeEndArray();
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }

    });

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    AddedLinksView<TestBean> view = new AddedLinksView<TestBean>(new TestBean("aa", 2L)) {
        @Override
        public Link[] buildLinks(TestBean resource) {
            return new Link[] { new Link("rel", "href://"), new Link("rel2", "href://2") };
        }

    };

    System.out.println("useModule json output: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(view));
}
```

Did I miss something obvious in Jackson to achieve this? Or am I completely off the mark in my requirements already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real way to externally inject things into POJOs to serialize: but you might be interested in checking out `@JsonAnyGetter`, which at least allows just adding contents of a `java.util.Map` as extra properties for a POJO.

Comment: I'll stick with my current solution since it does not add a jackson dependency on my model. But the day I cross that line I might scrap everything and use this @JsonAnyGetter.

Comment: Sure. Just make sure to read about mix-in annotations (wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations), since that way you need not add any Jackson types in your POJOs (although the "any getter" method is still needed of course)

Answer (score 0):

Would this answer your question: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureUpdateValue

I am not sure you can avoid mapping. You may use Dozer to help.

This should help you: [Tools for merging java beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683687/tools-for-merging-java-beans)

Comment: I was rather hoping to avoid having to merge beans, past experience of this king was rather bad. As for the http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureUpdateValue it seems to let you update an already existing bean with JSON encoded properties, what I'm looking to do is adding extra properties at serialization time.

Comment: There is something here: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_3_-_Merge_two_JSON_objects